# Polygon to Point Grid with the same information

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, point-in-polygon

I want a grid of points (with defined spaces between them) inside a Polygon. All the points should contain the same information as the original Polygon did.

I tried the centroid (only one point -> not good) also the random point (no information of the original Polygon -> also not good). Is there a simple way to do this in Qgis?

To show my thought-progress I added my poorly made picture of paint. The black circle represents the Polygon and the red dots should be my Point-grid.

[image: Paint picture of my problem]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Vector / Research Tools / Random Points in Polygons`, see screenshot.

If the points should be regular, select the top entry in the menu: `Vector / Research Tools / Create grid`. Then select points and set Grid extent to the polygon layer.
In both versions, you can set a fixed (grid) or minimal (random) distance and (for random points only) the number of points.

Then use `Join attributes by location (summary)` from `Menu Processing / Toolbox`. Set the points as input layer, the polygon as Join Layer. This will attributes from to polygon to a copy of the points layer.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create points in a uniform grid, there is a better process:

1. Run tool "Create Grid".

- Set grid type to point
- Set grid extent to "Calculate from Layer" and set it to your polygon layer
- Set your horizontal and vertical spacing. In this screenshot I have set it to get a square grid spaced at 10m x 10m.

[image: Create Grid]

2. Run tool "Clip"
   Clip your point layer using your polygon as an overlay layer.
3. Run tool join attributes by location.